# DisplayFor helper method render the ID of an entity, but doesn't pass it along the POST form collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, post, view, controller

I'm pretty sure this is because the form only POSTS inputs when submitting a form, no?

So when I recieve a POST response, the name I edited is correctly received but the ID is always set to 0.

Any workarounds?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var productBrand = brandRepo.FindProductBrand(id);
    ProductBrandModel model = Mapper.Map<ProductBrand, ProductBrandModel>(productBrand);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductBrandModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var productBrand = brandRepo.FindProductBrand(model.ProductBrandId);
        productBrand.Name = model.Name;
        brandRepo.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProductBrands");
    }
    return View(model);
}


/* THIS IS THE VIEW*/

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProductBrandModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductBrandId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductBrandId)
        </div> 

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>  

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I don't want to let the users edit the ID of the entity, only the name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about adding

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductBrandId)`

I think that will do what you want, if I understand your question.

Comment: +1 Basically what I was going to say. It's because you're not actually posting the Id back to the server; there is no form control containing that key value pair for the action method to pick up on.

Comment: Thanks, give me a second to try it out.